# Order of the "had" clause in conditional perfect

Tags: grammar, conditionals, clauses, conditional-perfect

I know that I can use "had" to construct a conditional perfect:

> Had it not rained yesterday, we would have finished painting the walls.

But is it grammatically correct to reverse the order of the clauses, like this?

> We would have finished painting the walls, had it not rained yesterday.

Comment: It merely changes the emphasis (and the second example is perhaps more likely as an apologetic explanation). Both are quite formal in speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically correct. Here are a few cases of this inversion, as found in the literature. As corrected by [**user Edwin Ashworth**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531493/order-of-the-had-clause-in-conditional-perfect#comment1297880_531495) it is not often found nowadays. However, for the particular instance "*had it not been for*" it is  still common enough.

- [The Parliamentary Debates from the Year 1803 to the Present Time](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MBBFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA333&dq=%22had+it+not%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1aexy6HpAhVR5uAKHdcECQMQ6AEIazAH#v=onepage&q=%22had%20it%20not%22&f=false) Great Britain. Parliament - 1820 -- Mr. Baring said, he should not have spoken had it not been for what had occurred within the last half hour.
- [The Parliamentary Debates from the Year 1803 to the Present Time](https://books.google.fr/books?id=k5hUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22had+it+not+been%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitj9DayaHpAhUb8uAKHRGMAPwQ6AEIyQEwEA#v=onepage&q=%22had%20it%20not%20been%22&f=false) 1821 -  […] he would not on that night have been in that House freely expressing his sentiments in debate, had it not been for the labours of some of the secret committees that […]
- [The Parliamentary Debates - Volume 13 - Page 975](https://books.google.fr/books?id=jhJFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA975&dq=%22had+it+not+been+for%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_iqnjx6HpAhWy0eAKHQvzA8UQ6AEItAEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22had%20it%20not%20been%20for%22&f=false) - 1826 -
  Great Britain. Parliament - 1826 - Well, then, he must have died, had it not been for the kindness of Mr. Brown, and the humanity of one of his fellow-prisoners.
- [The Parliamentary Debates (Authorized Edition)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ezZVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA717&dq=%22had+it+not%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1aexy6HpAhVR5uAKHdcECQMQ6AEItgEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22had%20it%20not%22&f=false) - 1832 - Great Britain. Parliament - 1832 -Member in the House, had it not been cheered by a solitary Member on the other side.
- [The history of the French revolution, tr. with notes by F. ... - Page 323](https://books.google.fr/books?id=imkEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA323&dq=%22had+it+not%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1aexy6HpAhVR5uAKHdcECQMQ6AEIkgIwFw#v=onepage&q=%22had%20it%20not%22&f=false) - 1838 -
  Marie Joseph L. Adolphe Thiers - 1838 - What would the patriots have said, had it not supported the Vaudois, punished the papal government, overthrown the King of Naples, and forced the sovereign of Piedmont to abdicate ?
- [Only 7 permits issued for cannabis retailers in Sask.](https://regina.ctvnews.ca/only-7-permits-issued-for-cannabis-retailers-in-sask-1.4138259?cache=yes%3FclipId%3D104069%3Fot%3DAjaxLayout%3FautoPlay%3Dtrue%3FautoPlay%3Dtrue) - Published Wednesday, October 17, 2018 12:35PM CST -  “It would have been better for our province had it not happened,” Justice Minister Don Morgan said at a press conference on Wednesday.
- [Snooker referee Olivier Marteel on virus frontline in Belgiu ..](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/more-sports/others/snooker-referee-olivier-marteel-on-virus-frontline-in-belgium/articleshow/75252434.cms) - 2020 - at the Crucible in Sheffield to officiate in this year's tournament had it not been postponed but instead he is working as a nurse in Veurne

---

- [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/dormant) - 2007 - Her talent might have lain dormant had it not been for her aunt's encouragement.
- [source couldn't be recovered] - 2010) - Tunisian man who was seriously injured in a fight more than five years ago would have died had it not been for an immediate intervention […]
- [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2019/12/10/greek-historians-may-have-lost-marbles-had-not-lord-elgin/) - 2019 - Why Greek historians may have lost their marbles had it not been for Lord Elgin.
- [Universal's Cabana Bay Beach Resort](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowUserReviews-g34515-d3932244-r700098478-Universal_s_Cabana_Bay_Beach_Resort-Orlando_Florida.html) - 2019 - i would've rated this property a 5 had it not been for my poolside experiences
- [3 Economic Policies That Made the COVID-19 Pandemic Worse Than It Had to Be](https://fee.org/articles/3-economic-policies-that-made-the-covid-19-pandemic-worse-than-it-had-to-be/) - 2020 - In fact, I think this crisis was largely preventable had it not been for this ignorance.
- [The Healing of Jordan Young: A 21st-Century Spiritual Guide to Health and ...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=NZ-PCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=had+it+not+been+for+Jordan%27s+blessing&source=bl&ots=qTYrtRJSrF&sig=ACfU3U3Jf_X5uG36dS1Jm6A7UU50OrmKYg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOvJ3d0qHpAhULrxoKHbDMAegQ6AEwCnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=had%20it%20not%20been%20for%20the%20fact&f=false) - 2015 - Had it not been for the fact that the lymphoma had infiltrated Jordan's lungs, Xalkory would have been out of the question due to legal limitations.
- [Malcom Turbull thought Petyer Dutton was "deluded"](https://10daily.com.au/news/politics/a200420tbdym/malcolm-turnbull-thought-peter-dutton-was-deluded-20200420)  - 2020 - Turnbull also claimed he believed he had the numbers to keep his position had it not been for Finance Minister Mathias Cormann, who he said […]

Comment: Where are these quotes from?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен They are taken from Google Books.

Comment: Please can you fill in which books you are quoting from, naming the author in each case.

Comment: If you need a style guide: [APA referencing](https://www.citethisforme.com/guides/apa)

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I'll try getting back to the sources and do that. Thanks for the link!